# javascript how to return elements from a list longer than given length

Tags: javascript

my professor gave me an assessment where i need to return all words from an `array` in a new array longer than given `length`
lets say i have a array

```
array = ["han", "hans", "hanssss", "hansssss", "hansss", "hansssssssss"];
```

and with function `getAllLongtextItems` i want to return all words longer than given length

```
function getAllLongTextItems(array, maxLength) {
  
}
```

how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```js
const array = ["han", "hans", "hanssss", "hansssss", "hansss", "hansssssssss"];

function getAllLongTextItems(array, maxLength) {
  return array.filter((item) => item.length > maxLength);
}

console.log(getAllLongTextItems(array, 6));
// ["hanssss", "hansssss", "hansssssssss"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.
Create a new empty array and push elements only if its length is greater than `maxLength`

```js
const array = ["han", "hans", "hanssss", "hansssss", "hansss", "hansssssssss"];

function getAllLongTextItems(array, maxLength) {
  const result = [];

  for (let str of array) {
    if (str.length > maxLength) result.push(str);
  }
  return result;
}

const result = getAllLongTextItems(array, 5);
console.log(result);
```

using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const array = ["han", "hans", "hanssss", "hansssss", "hansss", "hansssssssss"];

function getAllLongTextItems(array, maxLength) {
  return array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr.length > maxLength) acc.push(curr);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

const result = getAllLongTextItems(array, 5);
console.log(result);
```

using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const array = ["han", "hans", "hanssss", "hansssss", "hansss", "hansssssssss"];

function getAllLongTextItems(array, maxLength) {
  return array.filter((str) => str.length > maxLength);
}

const result = getAllLongTextItems(array, 5);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```js
array = ["han", "hans", "hanssss", "hansssss", "hansss", "hansssssssss"];

function getAllLongTextItems(array, maxLength) {
  return array.filter(item=>item.length>maxLength);
}

let returnarray= getAllLongTextItems(array,3);
console.log(returnarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

function getAllLongTextItems(array, maxLength) {

for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){

```
 if(array[i].length > maxLength){

    console.log(array[i]);
 }
```

}
}